# How to add new column in order csv export

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, export, order-grid, quantity

I am trying to add a new field called **quantity** to the order csv export, but I am not able to do it.

With all the other fields that get exported, I want another column called quantity which shows the **number of products** that have been purchased in every row for that order.

Can anyone kindly let me know how I can achieve this?

Comment: you have add new column in grid?

Comment: @RakeshDonga Yes, and that column should have a quantity of the products in that particular order.

Comment: you have add colomn in grid or not ?

Comment: I've not yet added it yet. I am yet to find out how to show the quantity of product in the column

Comment: you want to total quantity of ordered?

Comment: Yes. I want to show the number of products ordered in that order, in the new column I want to create

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91539/discussion-between-rakesh-donga-and-akshay-vasu).